# Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : NA/NaN/Inf in 'x' but no missing values

Tags: r, lm

I am working on doing linear regressions on data that I split into train, validation, and test. I have had an issue when I run a `lm` that I receive the error

> Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'.

I looked at other posts and tried a few things, but it is still not working.

Here is the model.

```
test_model <- lm(CVD ~ Exp_RFEI_2 + Low_Access + Gini_Index + Median_Income, data=test, NaRV.omit(Exp_RFEI_2))
```

I removed the missing values and double checked with

```
missing <- FINAL_df[!complete.cases(FINAL_df),]
```

I also added `NaRV.omit()` to handle any `Na/NaN/Inf`, but I still receive the error. I've noticed that if I change the degree of split (i.e. 80-10-10 vs. 75-15-15) or the set.seed that it changes where the error is thrown. Meaning depending on the condition the error may be in the valid list or the test list. So I know it's something with the data not with the code. I feel like I am missing something really simple!

Here is a sample of data.

```
structure(list(FIPS = "01001", State = "AL", County = "Autauga", 
    LACCESS_LOWI15 = 6543.67682386602, PCT_LACCESS_LOWI15 = 11.9911250002126, 
    FMRKT16 = 1, GROC14 = 4, SUPERC14 = 1, CONVS14 = 30, SPECS14 = 2, 
    FFR14 = 36, Value = 517.4, MILK_SODA_PRICE10 = 0.9232891, 
    PCT_SNAP16 = 16.9764357535007, `Estimate!!Gini Index` = 0.4227, 
    `Margin of Error!!Gini Index` = 0.0175, PCT_NHWHITE10 = 77.2461563834271, 
    PCT_NHBLACK10 = 17.5825988162211, PCT_HISP10 = 2.40054241263675, 
    PCT_NHASIAN10 = 0.855765882978138, PCT_NHNA10 = 0.397647101940591, 
    PCT_NHPI10 = 0.0403144527313042, PCT_65OLDER10 = 11.9953821626871, 
    PCT_18YOUNGER10 = 26.7779589892067, MEDHHINC15 = 56580, RFEI = 16.5, 
    Exp_RFEI_1 = 9.57142857142857, Exp_RFEI_2 = 8.25), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), na.action = structure(c(`68` = 68L, 
`69` = 69L, `70` = 70L, `71` = 71L, `72` = 72L, `73` = 73L, `74` = 74L, 
`75` = 75L, `76` = 76L, `77` = 77L, `78` = 78L, `79` = 79L, `80` = 80L, 
`81` = 81L, `82` = 82L, `83` = 83L, `84` = 84L, `85` = 85L, `86` = 86L, 
`87` = 87L, `88` = 88L, `89` = 89L, `90` = 90L, `91` = 91L, `92` = 92L, 
`93` = 93L, `94` = 94L, `95` = 95L, `96` = 96L, `541` = 541L, 
`547` = 547L, `548` = 548L, `549` = 549L, `550` = 550L, `551` = 551L, 
`613` = 613L, `755` = 755L, `778` = 778L, `1032` = 1032L, `1060` = 1060L, 
`1101` = 1101L, `1241` = 1241L, `1417` = 1417L, `1429` = 1429L, 
`1650` = 1650L, `1658` = 1658L, `1659` = 1659L, `1713` = 1713L, 
`1930` = 1930L, `1951` = 1951L, `2418` = 2418L, `2513` = 2513L, 
`2654` = 2654L, `2658` = 2658L, `2674` = 2674L, `2713` = 2713L, 
`2834` = 2834L, `2846` = 2846L, `2869` = 2869L, `2916` = 2916L, 
`2917` = 2917L, `2927` = 2927L, `3095` = 3095L, `3144` = 3144L, 
`3145` = 3145L, `3146` = 3146L, `3147` = 3147L, `3148` = 3148L, 
`3149` = 3149L, `3150` = 3150L, `3151` = 3151L, `3152` = 3152L, 
`3153` = 3153L, `3154` = 3154L, `3155` = 3155L, `3156` = 3156L, 
`3157` = 3157L, `3158` = 3158L, `3159` = 3159L, `3160` = 3160L, 
`3161` = 3161L, `3162` = 3162L, `3163` = 3163L, `3164` = 3164L, 
`3165` = 3165L, `3166` = 3166L, `3167` = 3167L, `3168` = 3168L, 
`3169` = 3169L, `3170` = 3170L, `3171` = 3171L, `3172` = 3172L, 
`3173` = 3173L, `3174` = 3174L, `3175` = 3175L, `3176` = 3176L, 
`3177` = 3177L, `3178` = 3178L, `3179` = 3179L, `3180` = 3180L, 
`3181` = 3181L, `3182` = 3182L, `3183` = 3183L, `3184` = 3184L, 
`3185` = 3185L, `3186` = 3186L, `3187` = 3187L, `3188` = 3188L, 
`3189` = 3189L, `3190` = 3190L, `3191` = 3191L, `3192` = 3192L, 
`3193` = 3193L, `3194` = 3194L, `3195` = 3195L, `3196` = 3196L, 
`3197` = 3197L, `3198` = 3198L, `3199` = 3199L, `3200` = 3200L, 
`3201` = 3201L, `3202` = 3202L, `3203` = 3203L, `3204` = 3204L, 
`3205` = 3205L, `3206` = 3206L, `3207` = 3207L, `3208` = 3208L, 
`3209` = 3209L, `3210` = 3210L, `3211` = 3211L, `3212` = 3212L, 
`3213` = 3213L, `3214` = 3214L, `3215` = 3215L, `3216` = 3216L, 
`3217` = 3217L, `3218` = 3218L, `3219` = 3219L, `3220` = 3220L, 
`3221` = 3221L, `3222` = 3222L, `3223` = 3223L, `3224` = 3224L, 
`3225` = 3225L, `3226` = 3226L, `3227` = 3227L, `3228` = 3228L, 
`3229` = 3229L), class = "omit"))
```

Comment: Your source data contains only a single observation.  It's unreasonable to attempt a linear regression with only one x and one y value.

Comment: Your code looks  okay, so we likely would need to see enough of the data to reproduce your error. You will be able to share more rows of your data if you only include the variables used in the regression model in your `dput`. It also seems unlikely `NaRV.omit` is required (ps. while it is unlikely to be the culprit to your modelling problems it is worth converting your variable names to syntactically valid names)

Comment: Here is my script from my github so that you can see the test data frame that is giving me an issue. I took your advice and renamed the variable names. https://github.com/TheDariaEdits/Food-Swamps/blob/master/Food%20Swamp%20script.R

Comment: Thanks. Some columns have infinite values; `names(FINAL_df)[sapply(FINAL_df, function(x) any(is.infinite(x)))]` so Id remove these prior to the modelling. So at [line 73](https://github.com/TheDariaEdits/Food-Swamps/blob/master/Food%20Swamp%20script.R#L73) i'd add `FINAL_df[] <- lapply(FINAL_df, function(x) replace(x, is.infinite(x), NA))` .(and you can probably get rid of all the `NaRV.omit` stuff)

Comment: I will try and let you know. The Exp_RFEI_2 variable is a calculated variable so I didn't want to delete the counties based off of it and tried NaRv.omit. But it seems like I will need to.

Comment: Ok it worked @user20650. I'm not sure why the other linear models were not having the same error code, because I checked and they had infinite values as well... So while the code works and I can move forward I am definitely going to have to look deeper into the issue. :) Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. ps I'd definitely  remove the `NaRV.omit` stuff as I don't think it is doing what you expect. It is in the position of the `subset` argument and while ive not really inspected the results  I think its likely something unexpected is happening.  `lm` will take care of the missing (`NA`) data for you

Comment: Will do! It'd be great if you can put your solution as an answer that qay I can close this out and give you credit for all of your help!

Comment: Please feel free to write it up